# I seek some campaign setting, but I only remember the description of one creature from this

Tags: product-identification, campaign-settings

I'm looking for one setting. I read one d20 rule book about 10 years ago. There was described a large angel-like humanoid creature of epic level, which was painful just to be in the material plane, and all those present next to him were crying because of regrets for the sins they had committed. The creature was blue and white, if I remember correctly.
Has anyone ever seen anything like this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I believe you're thinking of the Eidoneus, a "lumina" from the *Legends of Avadnu* book. It's a CR 31 Good Outsider and it's very blue and white. The lumina are "extraplanar beings of purity and light from a distant realm, as alien as they are good...Lumina almost never leave their homeworld willingly...To a lumina, the mortal world seems an almost intrinsically evil place, where only the most pure individuals show even a glimmer of goodness." So it's less that it's painful for them to be on the material plane, and more that it's horrifying and evil.

The Eidoneus is the one with the aura of regret.

> **Aura of Regret (Su):** Any creature within 60 feet of an eidoneus must succeed on a DC 44 Will save or be stunned, fall prone, and begin to weep over its past sins.

The world is called Avadnu, and *Legends of Avadnu* has a section on page 22 explaining how lumina fit into Avadnu. The setting itself is called *Violet Dawn: the Time of the Unraveling.*

Comment: Yes, that's it! Thanks for helping me find it.

Comment: @arthur Generally, it's good practice to wait a day or so before accepting an answer. In this case, where you have a complete and correct answer, you can accept it right away by clicking the green check mark.